# Manipulating an equation in statistics

Tags: statistics

We have $y = X\alpha + \xi$, where $\xi\sim N(0, 1)$ and $\xi = (\xi_1\,,\xi_2\,,\xi_3\,,\xi_4)^T$. Moreover $X$ is a 4x4 design matrix such that $x_i$ is a column 4x1 column vector made up of 1's, -1's and 0's and $\alpha = (\alpha_1\,\, \alpha_2\,\, \alpha_3\,\, \alpha_5)$

My lecture notes then say,

$\hat\alpha = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\sim N(\alpha\,,\,\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$

why?

Comment if more clarity is required and I will edit the question.

Comment: Shouldn't $\xi$ be a multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: Yes it should I will try and make it clearer in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=X\alpha+\xi$, where $\xi\sim \mathcal{N}_4(0,\Sigma)$. First we note that $\hat{\alpha}$ does indeed follow a $4$-dimensional normal distribution since normal distributions are closed under linear transformations. Thus it suffices to find the mean and variance of $\hat{\alpha}$. The mean is 
$$
{\rm E}[\hat{\alpha}]=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T{\rm E}[y]=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T (X\alpha+{\rm E}[\xi])=\alpha
$$
and the variance
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\alpha})&=\left[(X X^T)^{-1}X^T\right] \Sigma\left[(X X^T)^{-1}X^T\right]^T\\
\end{align}
$$
by [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of the multivariate normal distribution. If $\Sigma$ is of the form $\sigma^2\cdot I_4$ then the variance simplifies to 
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\alpha})=\sigma^2(XX^T)^{-1}.
$$
Note that you have a mysterious $\sigma$ in your formula which does not appear anywhere else in your question. You probably meant it to be included in the variance of $\xi$.